# Laravel Post Controller Method and PostController not Working

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

My Laravel blog project the get method of postcontroller is working but post method is not working. I redirect The Post Method. But Accordind to my my code it should return to my Admin page.My Controller Code is

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Post;
use App\Category;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function getBlogIndex() {
        return view('frontend.blog.index');
    }

    public function getSinglePost($post_id,$end='frontend') {
        return view($end . '.blog.single');
    }

    public function getCreatePost() {
        return view('admin.blog.create_post');
    }

    public function postCreatePost(Request $request ) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:120|unique:posts',
            'author' => 'required|max:80',
            'body' => 'required'
            ]);

        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $request['title'];
        $post->author = $request['author'];
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.index')->with(['success' => 'Post Successfully Created']);
    }
}
```

My Routes file

```
    <?php


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::group([
        'prefix' =>'/admin'
        ], function() {
            Route::get('/', [
                'uses' => 'AdminController@getIndex',
                'as' => 'admin.index'
            ]);

            Route::get('/blog/posts/create', [
                    'uses' => 'PostController@getCreatePost',
                    'as' => 'admin.blog.create_post'
            ]);

            Route::get('/blog/post/create', [
                    'uses' => 'PostController@postCreatePost',
                    'as' => 'admin.blog.post.create'
            ]);
        });
});
```

My  form is

```
@extends('layouts.admin-master')

@section('styles')
    {!! Html::style('src/css/form.css') !!} 

@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        @include('includes.info-box')
        <form action="{{ route('admin.blog.post.create') }}" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'class=has-error' : '' }} value="{{ Request::old('title') }}">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="author">Author</label>
                <input type="text" name="author" id="author" {{ $errors->has('author') ? 'class=has-error' : '' }} value="{{ Request::old('author') }}">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="category_select">Add Category</label>
                <select name="category_select" id="category_select">
                    <option value="Dummy Category ID">Dummy Category</option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" class="btn">Add Category</button>
                <div class="added-categories">
                    <ul></ul>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="categories" id="categories">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="body">Body</label>
                <textarea name="body" id="body" rows="12" {{ $errors->has('body') ? 'class=has-error' : '' }} >{{ Request::old('body') }}</textarea>

            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn">Create Post</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    {!! Html::script('src/js/posts.js') !!}
@endsection
```

When I submit My post I shows this
[image]

I dont find where the problem is. Plz Help Me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an extremely common error and a good one to look out for. Whenever you see:

> **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** in RouteCollection.php

The very first thing you should check is your routes file to make sure you have `Route::get` or `Route::post` correctly based on what you are trying to do.

Your issue is that your form sends the data as POST, but your route is GET.

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.blog.post.create') }}" method="post">
```

and

```
Route::get('/blog/post/create', [
   'uses' => 'PostController@postCreatePost',
   'as' => 'admin.blog.post.create'
]);
```

Change that to `Route::post` for it to function correctly.

Comment: @Jahid26 Please mark this as the selected answer if this correctly addressed the issue.